# Call to createContext in react-leaflet/es/context.js fails

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

./node_modules/react-leaflet/es/context.js
node_modules/react-leaflet/es/context.js:8

```
// $FlowFixMe: import
forwardRef } from 'react';

var _createContext = createContext({}), // This line fails
    Consumer = _createContext.Consumer,
    Provider = _createContext.Provider;
```

Answer (score 4):

Just ran into this, you need to upgrade to React 16.3 or above as react-leaflet is using the context API.

```
npm i -S react react-dom
```

That should do it.

Comment: Yes, thats right: `createContext` calls from https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/blob/master/src/context.js#L14

and `react-leaflet` requires at least `react ^16.3.0` and `react-dom ^ 16.3.0`, see
https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/blob/master/package.json#L59-L60